# How can I tell which of the alternatives matched in a Perl regular expression pattern?

Tags: regex, perl, capture, regex-group

I have a list of regular expressions (about 10 - 15) that I needed to match against some text. Matching them one by one in a loop is too slow. But instead of writing up my own state machine to match all the regexes at once, I am trying to `|` the individual regexes and let perl do the work. The problem is that how do I know which of the alternatives matched?

This question addresses the case where there are no capturing groups inside each individual regex. ([which portion is matched by regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701454/how-can-i-know-which-portion-of-a-perl-regex-is-matched-by-a-string)) What if there are capturing groups inside each regexes?

So with the following,

```
/^(A(\d+))|(B(\d+))|(C(\d+))$/
```

and the string "A123", how can I both know that A123 matched and extract "123"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to code up your own state machine to combine regexes. Look into [Regexp:Assemble](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Assemble). It has methods that'll track which of your initial patterns matched.

Edit:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.012;

use Regexp::Assemble;

my $string = 'A123';

my $re = Regexp::Assemble->new(track => 1);
for my $pattern (qw/ A(\d+) B(\d+) C(\d+) /) {
  $re->add($pattern);
}

say $re->re; ### (?-xism:(?:A(\d+)(?{0})|B(\d+)(?{2})|C(\d+)(?{1})))
say for $re->match($string); ### A(\d+)
say for $re->capture; ### 123
```

Comment: I found *exactly* what I needed in the "Tracking" section of README of the module. - I needed to dispatch on a specific pattern match. Great tool.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use `/^ (?<prefix> A|B|C) (?<digits> \d+) $/x`. Note, named capture groups used for clarity, and not essential.

Answer (score 3):

`A123` will be in capture group `$1` and `123` will be in group `$2`

So you could say:

```
if ( /^(A(\d+))|(B(\d+))|(C(\d+))$/ && $1 eq 'A123' && $2 eq '123' ) {
    ...
}
```

This is redundant, but you get the idea...

**EDIT:** No, you don't have to enumerate each sub match, you asked how to know whether `A123` matched and how to extract `123`:

- You won't enter the `if` block unless `A123` matched
- and you can extract `123` using the `$2` backreference.

So maybe this example would have been more clear:

```
if ( /^(A(\d+))|(B(\d+))|(C(\d+))$/ ) {
    # do something with $2, which will be '123' assuming $_ matches /^A123/
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

To capture matches in an AoA (which is a different question, but this should do it):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @matches = map { [$1,$2] if /^(?:(A|B|C)(\d+))$/ } <DATA>;
print Dumper \@matches;

__DATA__
A123
B456
C769
```

Result:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'A',
            '123'
          ],
          [
            'B',
            '456'
          ],
          [
            'C',
            '769'
          ]
        ];
```

Note that I modified your regex, but it looks like that's what you're going for judging by your comment...

Comment: So I have to enumerate the number of parenthesis in each sub regex manually then? I was hoping for something like an array inside array, like @groups = ($_ =~ /^(A(\d+))|(B(\d+))|(C(\d+))$/) and $group[1]->[0] would match "123". Not possible?

Comment: If there are arbitrary number capturing groups inside each sub regex then knowing $3 (for example) matched would not help me find out which sub regex matched without first figuring out which $? correspond to which capture.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can do in Perl is to embed Perl code directly in your regex using "(?{...})". So, you can set a variable that tells you which part of the regex matched. WARNING: your regex should not contain any variables (outside of the embedded Perl code), that will be interpolated into the regex or you will get errors. Here is a sample parser that uses this feature:

```
my $kind;
my $REGEX  = qr/
          [A-Za-z][\w]*                        (?{$kind = 'IDENT';})
        | (?: ==? | != | <=? | >=? )           (?{$kind = 'OP';})
        | -?\d+                                (?{$kind = 'INT';})
        | \x27 ( (?:[^\x27] | \x27{2})* ) \x27 (?{$kind = 'STRING';})
        | \S                                   (?{$kind = 'OTHER';})
        /xs;

my $line = "if (x == 'that') then x = -23 and y = 'say ''hi'' for me';";
my @tokens;
while ($line =~ /( $REGEX )/xsg) {
    my($match, $str) = ($1,$2);
    if ($kind eq 'STRING') {
        $str =~ s/\x27\x27/\x27/g;
        push(@tokens, ['STRING', $str]);
        }
    else {
        push(@tokens, [$kind, $match]);
        }
    }
foreach my $lItems (@tokens) {
    print("$lItems->[0]: $lItems->[1]\n");
    }
```

which prints out the following:

```
IDENT: if
OTHER: (
IDENT: x
OP: ==
STRING: that
OTHER: )
IDENT: then
IDENT: x
OP: =
INT: -23
IDENT: and
IDENT: y
OP: =
STRING: say 'hi' for me
OTHER: ;
```

It's kind of contrived, but you'll notice that the quotes (actually, apostrophes) around strings are stripped off (also, consecutive quotes are collapsed to single quotes), so in general, only the $kind variable will tell you whether the parser saw an identifier or a quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

With your example data, it is easy to write

```
'A123' =~ /^([ABC])(\d+)$/;
```

after which $1 will contain the prefix and $2 the suffix.

I cannot tell whether this is relevant to your real data, but to use an additional module seems like overkill.

Comment: That ABC 123 was just an example, I have more complicated patterns that I read from other modules at run time. So using Regexp::Assemble is justified.